# Tmux key-bind like to use the windows/super for my meta key in Tmux Without X

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I have RaspberryPI with no GUI==(no x.org) I like to bind the useless window/super key to be my prefix. Using Arch for ARM runs great.

If think this is going to take more then simple mod in the tmux.conf file.

After some Googling found post with a command:
 dumpkeys | grep -E "keycode *125|126"
That command give me a blank line.

Comment: Their is no X running on the system.

Comment: I know a the top tell me question has been answered but in fact none of the answer on the question work without X.

Comment: Using `showkey` i got 125 as keycode when i hit the meta key on my machine. Created a file with content 'keycode 125 = Control_b', added it the the keymap with `loadkeys`, launched tmux (default config) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
1  ### command prefix 
2  unbind C-b
3  set-option -g prefix Super_L
```

If it's not working, check your `xterm` settings, environment variable(s). Can you run `xev` to check what it says when you press the key? Sorry, I hadn't seen the last part of the question at first :p

Also, check out [this linuxforums thread](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/miscellaneous/6173-how-do-i-find-keycode.html) for some more information on keybindings, and the programs `xmodmap` and `xbindkeys`

Comment: I am not running x on my pie so none of the x stuff is their. So got bad key:Super-L when reload my tmux.conf

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not so easy, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/how-do-i-bind-the-tmux-prefix-to-a-super