# How to bind (double-)tapping the Shift-Key in tmux?

Tags: terminal, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I would like to bind the `tmux` `find-window` prompt to pressing and releasing <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice.

I have already tried

```
bind-key -n S-S command-prompt "find-window -N '%%'"
```

This results in no error message, checked with `:show-messages`, but does not trigger the action when double-tapping <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: for us using tmux on macos i posted this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413472/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [xcape](/questions/tagged/xcape) under [x11](/questions/tagged/x11) to configure <kbd>Shift</kbd> to emit e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> when tapped and released. Then you would declare that as a secondary `tmux` escape key, and assign a Key-binding to "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>" for `command-prompt "find-window -N '%%'"`

The exact sequence of commands:

At shell prompt:

```
$ xcape -e 'Shift_L=Alt_L|Control_R|Shift_L|F12'
```

At tmux prompt:

```
:set-option prefix2 "M-C-S-F12"
:bind M-C-S-F12 command-prompt "find-window -N '%%'"
```

Now double-tap <kbd>Shift_L</kbd>, and on the bottom left of your `tmux`you will see `(find-window)`.

With `Shift_R=Alt_L|Control_R|Shift_L|F11` you can use <kbd>Shift_L</kbd> for inner `tmux`, and <kbd>Shift_R</kbd> for outer `tmux`, if you nest them.

Note: I had previously posted this answer with <kbd>F15</kbd>, but that did not work as expected , because [@Gilles says: `F13` - `F20` need to be declared in `terminfo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1686/127903).